# filter for regrouping elements won't work

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter, element

```js
let wrap = document.querySelector(".wrap");
let temp = document.querySelector(".temp");
temp.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  // returns pragraph of children[0]. Works fine.
  console.log(wrap.children[0].firstElementChild);

  // returns list of all lis, not pragraphs.
  let filtered = Array.from(wrap.children).filter(item => item.firstElementChild);
  console.log(filtered);
})
```

```html
    <div>
      <ul class="wrap">
        <li>
          <p class="temp">outer 1</p>
          <ul>
            <li>inset 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>outer 2</p>
          <ul>
            <li>inset 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>outer 3</p>
          <ul>
            <li>inset 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>outer 4</p>
          <ul>
            <li>inset 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>outer 5</p>
          <ul>
            <li>inset 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>outer 6</p>
          <ul>
            <li>inset 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>outer 7</p>
          <ul>
            <li>inset 1</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to regroup all `p`s each of every `li`s by using `filter` method, but the function keeps working weirdly.

```
// returns pragraph of children[0]. Works fine.
console.log(wrap.children[0].firstElementChild);
```

Inspecting single paragraph with `.firstElementChild` works just perfectly fine. However, when I use `filter()`, this happenes:

```
// returns list of all lis, not pragraphs.
let filtered = Array.from(wrap.children).filter(item => item.firstElementChild);
// result: temp.js:5 (7) [li, li, li, li, li, li, li]
```

I was using filter like this ages ago but somewhat reason it won't work anymore.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `map()` not `filter()`

```
let filtered = Array.from(wrap.children).map(item => item.firstElementChild);
```

Comment: Your code is the exact same as in the question.

Comment: @echomyfield Accept the answer if you are satisfied and feel free to ask anything if you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) gives you a `map()` for free. (*Array.from(arrayLike [, mapFn [, thisArg]])*)

```
let filtered = Array.from(wrap.children, item => item.firstElementChild);
```

---

`filter()` expects a boolean to be returned from the callback and includes the element being iterated if `true` or omits it if `false`.

Your call `Array.from(wrap.children).filter(item => item.firstElementChild);` returns an array of elements in `wrap.children` for which `.firstChildElement` returns `true`.

Comment: That's another useful tip that I missed. Thanks a lot.